# How can I get the first character for string1 and string2 from the text box

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox.text = "Item1 Item2", how can I pick the first character for Item1 and Item2.
I would like to be able to have as a result I and I characters only.
I'm using in my code textbox.text.substring(0,1) but this will give me the first character for Item1, how can I get the first character for Item2.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

PS I'm using VB.NET code, visual studio 2019

Comment: So basically you are asking us how to split a String on a space, so you should be searching for that on the web instead of asking us at all. This question has nothing to do with TextBoxes or getting the first character of a String. The issue is purely splitting the String on a space. If you identify what the actual issue is then you can look for solutions to that issue, which is what you should be doing.

Comment: It's not just about knowing the answer. It's about whether the question is of a standard that is acceptable on SO. This one is not and thus should not be answered. If you continue to post substandard questions then you're likely to see them get closed. If no one told you why they were being closed, you'd get narky about that instead. I have told you why, thereby helping you avoid having your questions closed. If you ignore the information provided then you ought not complain when it inevitably happens.

Answer (score 1):

You already know how to get the first character from a string. What's left is to split the textbox's string into it's words.

You can use [Strings.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split) for that.

Here's a short example:

```
Dim s As String = "hello my friend"
Dim words As String() = s.Split()
' words content: "hello", "my", "friend"
```

Have fun.

Comment: You have included a link to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split` but the code you posted uses `System.String.Split`. The latter is the more appropriate option so you should fix the link.

Comment: Also, the overload of `Split` that you're calling accepts a `ParamArray` of discrete `Char` delimiters so there's no need to explicitly create an array: `s.Split(" "c)`. Furthermore, if you provide no arguments at all then it will split on whitespace by default so you don't actually need any argument to split on spaces unless you specifically don't want to split on other whitespace characters: `s.Split()`.

Comment: Nice catch, next time I'll be more aware about this. I'll update this real quick...

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, you just need to find where the first letter of the second item starts.  To do that you can find the position of the space and add 1 to it.  To find the first space, you can use the IndexOf function as follows:

```
Dim s as String = "Item1 Item2"
Dim letterOne as String = s.Substring(0, 1)
Dim letterTwo as String = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(" ") + 1, 1)
```

Of course in anything you do, you have to pro-act to errors, for example, if there are no items, or just one - but the above should be at the core of what you are looking for.

Comment: no problem, glad to help.  If you like the answer, please check it off as accepted